# Prove that $\tan^{-1}(1/n)+\tan^{-1}(2/n)+\cdots+\tan^{-1}(n/n)$ increases as $n$ increases

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, inverse-function, trigonometric-series

> Let 
>   $$f(n)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)+ \cdots +\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)$$
>   where $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Prove that $f(n)$ increases as $n$ increases.

I first tried to create telescopic sum, but it seems that it is impossible to do so.

I tried to find all $n$ such that
 $f(n+1)-f(n)≥0$,
 this would give me terms like
 $\tan^{-1}(r/n) -\tan^{-1}(r/n+1)$ ,
which I would simplify using the formula for inverse tangents' sum and difference, but this made it worse.

I used a graphing calculator to find that: as
$ x→∞,f(n)→∞$ and hence $f$ doesn't converge.

Then i tried to approximate 
$f(n);f(n+1)$ 
as linear functions such that
 $f(n)<k(n)$ and $f(n+1)>q(n+1)$,
such that $q(n+1)≥k(n)$

but I could not find any.

Comment: What does "$tan^-$" mean?

Comment: It's the tangent inverse function.

Comment: The function as you've defined it does not appear to have a maximum. It increases monotonically and without bound with increasing $n$.

Comment: Yes but I want to prove that it is an increasing function to show that there exists no such "theta".

Comment: I see. Perhaps you should edit the question make it more clear that that's what you're asking.

Comment: Could some Riemann sum prove useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice for any $1 \le k \le n$,

$$\frac{k+1}{n+1} - \frac{k}{n} = \frac{n-k}{n(n+1)} \ge 0
\implies \tan^{-1}\frac{k+1}{n+1} \ge \tan^{-1}\frac{k}{n}$$
We have
$$f(n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\tan^{-1}\frac{k}{n+1} = \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{n+1} +
\sum_{k=1}^n \tan^{-1}\frac{k+1}{n+1}
> \sum_{k=1}^n\tan^{-1}\frac{k}{n} = f(n)$$

Comment: Did you mean to type $\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{n+1}$ after the second equals sign on the last line?

Comment: @JohnBarber yup, that's a typo, thanks for pointing that out.